# How can I sort an array of strings based on the number of instances a string appears in an element?

Tags: swift, swift3

How can I sort an array of strings based on the number of instances a string appears in an element? For example:

```
let str = "o"
let arrayOfStrings = ["Hot", "Only open on tuesdays", "People of earth"]

//Sort here

//arrayOfString becomes ["Only open on tuesdays", "People of earth", "Hot"]
```

Comment: So, by this example, you mean the number of times the string "o" appears?

Comment: Correct. The array is sorted according to how many times the string "o" appears

Comment: Is `str` always a single character?

Comment: This solution would have to work with a string as well as a single character.

Comment: What would be the number of instances of "oo" in "aooob"? 1 or 2?

Comment: In that case the number of instances would be 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import Foundation
let str = "o"
var arrayOfStrings = ["Hot", "Only open on tuesdays", "People of earth"]

arrayOfStrings.sort {
  return $0.components(separatedBy: str).count < $1.components(separatedBy: str).count
}

print(arrayOfStrings)
// ["Hot", "Only open on tuesdays", "People of earth"]
```

Note that this is the correct order if I sort the highest instances last. I went from least to most instances to show you this: the string "o" and the string "O" are two different strings so the count in your original `Array` was 1, 2, 2. If you want to compare the strings case-insensitively you have to apply an uppercase or lowercase operation to the comparison.

Here is the result with most instances of the string first, using case-insensitive comparison:

```
arrayOfStrings.sort {
  let upper = str.uppercased()
  return $0.uppercased().components(separatedBy: upper).count >
    $1.uppercased().components(separatedBy: upper).count
}

print(arrayOfStrings)
// ["Only open on tuesdays", "People of earth", "Hot"]
```

Comment: This would count one instance of "oo" in "aooob", not two.

Comment: @MartinR very true, depending on the desired behavior that may be good or bad. Good call on clarifying that.

Answer (score 2):

First define a function which computes the number of occurrences of
a substring in a string, including overlapping occurrences:

```
extension String {
    /// Compute number of occurrences of a substring, including overlapping occurrences.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - substring: The substring to search for
    ///   - options: String compare options, e.g. `.caseInsensitive` (optional)
    /// - Returns: The number of occurrences of `substring` in `self`
    func count(of substring: String, options: CompareOptions = []) -> Int {
        var count = 0
        var pos = startIndex
        // Find next occurrence of `substring`:
        while let r = range(of: substring, options: options, range: pos..<endIndex) {
            count += 1
            // Continue search at the next character position:
            pos = index(after: r.lowerBound)
        }
        return count
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
"Only open on tuesdays".count(of: "o", options: .caseInsensitive) == 3
"aooob".count(of: "oo") == 2
```

This can be used to sort a string array according to the number
of occurrences of a substring (explanations inline):

```
let str = "o"
let arrayOfStrings = ["Hot", "Only open on tuesdays", "People of earth"]

// Compute number of occurrences of `str` for each array element:
let counts = arrayOfStrings.map { $0.count(of: str, options: .caseInsensitive) }
print(counts) // [1, 3, 2]

// Sort array indices according to number of occurences of `str` in array element (decreasing):
let sortedIndices = arrayOfStrings.indices.sorted(by: { counts[$0] > counts[$1] })
print(sortedIndices) // [1, 2, 0]

// Create new array from sorted array indices:
let sortedArray = sortedIndices.map { arrayOfStrings[$0] }
print(sortedArray) // ["Only open on tuesdays", "People of earth", "Hot"]
```